# React - How can a DOM-Element that is passed by Parameter be manipulated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, getelementbyid, dom-manipulation

So let's imagine the following scenario:

```
const ExampleComponent = ({categories, item}:{categories: string,item:JSX.Element|JSX.Element[]}) => {

    return <div>
         <div>{categories}</div>
         <item/>
    </div>
}
```

Furthermore there is a place where this component is being used:

```
return <div>
    <ExampleComponent categories="a,b,c,d">
      <div>I want to be replaced with categories/use the categories parameter</div>
    </ExampleComponent>
    <ExampleComponent categories="e,f,g,h">
      <div>different div here</div>
      <div>I want to be replaced with categories/use the categories parameter</div>
    </ExampleComponent>
</div>
```

The ExampleComponent itself wants to use Categories, but there are also components in ExampleComponent's children that want to get in touch with Categories.

What options do I have now to use Categories? My initial idea was to give the place in the children an id and then use `getElementById` on it to replace the content, but I have often read that `GetElementById` is something that goes against the philosophies of ReactJS.
Could someone provide a clarification why `GetElementById` is a bad idea and how the problem could be solved otherwise?

Comment: cuz when you use `getElementById`, you're directly manipulating the `DOM` outside of React's control, which can lead to inconsistencies and bugs.